# Add new Microsoft Edge to web browser control?

Tags: c#, webkit, webbrowser-control, windows-10, microsoft-edge

The new Windows 10 with Microsoft Edge has arrived. How can I add it to my web browser control? I need it because the actual web browser control doesn't allow JavaScript and CSS3.

I used to also add Chrome browser with the projects WebKit and Awesomium but they didn't remember the login credentials (I need them for my app), so I have to use I.E. unfortunately.

Comment: This feature is not available yet. You can upvote here https://insider.windows.com/en-gb/fb/?contextid=390&feedbackid=d2fe755c-1f5a-4637-9f45-8b1c33346eb6&form=1 or https://aka.ms/Hinq7o

Answer (score 39):

UPDATE Jan 2021: WebView2 has been released. This enables integration of the Chromium based Edge as a web control. It's a lot more complicated to use, unfortunately, but a lot more powerful. Works with WinForms or WPF or C++ apps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

UPDATE May 2018: FINALLY Microsoft has made it easy.
https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/

For now, the new control is in the Windows Community Toolkit 3.0 and contained in Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.dll, which you may need to manually add a reference to.

======
I wish somebody had mentioned this, so I'll add this because it doesn't look like webbrowser control will ever be updated.

Use the WebView control instead. This uses EdgeHTML rendering engine. This is part of WindowPresentation layer <del>but it is possible to link from WinForms and presumably other apps.</del> You must convert to a UWP app

```
import Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView
```

Example code: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7

I haven't replaced my WebBrowser with WebView yet, but the interface looks pretty familiar.

Comment: well, I guess this requires UWP after all. I thought I'd read of a way to use those controls in a desktop app, but apparently that's wishful thinking.

Comment: I commented long ago but I just edited. Some UWP APIs can be used, but unfortunately not the WebView. You could convert to a UWP app using Desktop Bridge and use WebView and still call non-UWP code.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Might want to review this again. Edge is being killed off. Don't know how it will affect the controls. I am still trying to get more info on this.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey is there a way to user WebView with .NET Framework 4.6.1?

Comment: Has been updated again - now separate NuGet packages available for WinForms, WPF, and UWP (Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView, Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView, Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.WebView)

Comment: Is it easier to disable header/footer from printing out using WebView2 than the old browser control that you had to edit registry to disable?

Comment: @DanielP everything about WebView2 is a lot harder. I'm not sure you can disable printing completely. It runs chromium in a separate process and intercepting Ctrl-P wasn't initially possible, but I think it is now.

Comment: Having just spent two days NOT successfully replacing WebBrowser with WebView2 in our class library, I consider the latter to be a bit of a dog. Waaaay more complicated , fussy and fragile and possibly not even usable (for us) due to embedding issues. I hate it, to be blunt.

Comment: In addition to the other issues: WebView2 is not part of the WinAPI - it's a 3rd party (i.e. not Windows) component. And i'm really not going to ship dll's with my single `.exe` appliation.

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunately it seems that there is currently no way to use Edge in a MS webbrowser control without using third party addons. While the proposed "solution" to add dword:00002ee1 to FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION causes the webbrowser to (falsely) report Edge/12.9200_AGENT as USER_AGENT, in fact it still uses the Trident engine to render the web content. So it seems that Microsoft had planned to support Edge in webbrowser control but did not get finished and forgot to take out the corresponding Emulation key. You can verify this by browsing to http://html5test.com/ where the webbrowser control scores between 342 and 347 points (the same as IE11), while Edge scores 397 points.

Comment: I've raised a bug in the Edge feedback site at this location https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7749954/ +1-ing it might help accelerate the development of an Edge Browser Control

Comment: Can you give some examples of those third party add-on?

Comment: Use the below link to open Feedback hub app and up vote the issue

https://insider.windows.com/en-gb/fb/?contextid=390&feedbackid=d2fe755c-1f5a-4637-9f45-8b1c33346eb6&form=1 or https://aka.ms/Hinq7o

Answer (score 19):

**UPDATE** As stated in @MartinKasztantowicz' answer, as of now (mid Feb '16) there is no known way to load the *real* Edge rendering engine.
The following sets the control to *report the new user agent* but *uses the old engine for rendering*. It is useful nevertheless for e.g. persuading sites to turn off deprecated IE hacks.

The browser version of `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` is controlled *per application* by a registry key. If your users are on Windows 10, you can tell the control to <strike>load</strike> *fake* Edge by adding the following key:

- For 64bit applications, 32bit only Windows or current user: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
  "Example.exe"=dword:00002ee1` respectively `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...]`
- For 32bit applications on 64 bit machines (only machine-wide): `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
  "Example.exe"=dword:00002ee1`

For more information and values, check the corresponding [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)#browser-emulation)

I just tested, and got the following result... don't know whether there are any values to also report Windows 10:

[image]

Comment: `HKCU\Software` is not redirected

Comment: @CaringDev I don't believe that it is the site not recognizing Win10 yet as this problem still persists and with actually using Edge this does not appear. I have read that it is a default registry error with the webBrowser control, for the life of me I cannot remember where though

Comment: @CodyFidler Yes, as stated in the update, this is a well known problem. I've now removed the parenthesized sentence about the site.

Comment: This just makes the server believe that this is Edge, but it still does not support HTML5 elements that are supported in Edge, its just the same old ie, but pretends as Edge..

Comment: @VibeeshanRC Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: @CaringDev - how come the user agent of WebBrowser on Windows 10 stated that it is on Windows 8 (Windows NT 6.2)? Is there away to fix that? I have 3rd party content that fails as a result.. it thinks its css engine is on Win8 but actually it behaves as Win10 one..  WebBrowser userAgent `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT **6.2**; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.9200` Edge userAgent `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT **10.0**; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240`

Comment: @MichalTsadok I think there is still no way to fix, unless you use the new UWP WebView control (see other answer).

Comment: i did excatly as you did but i'm getting MSIE 7 all the time- can you share you r example?

Comment: [Microsoft has made this much easier now](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/)

Comment: i had 99999 as the value which fakes edge, but breaks youtube, put 11001 then youtube works. hmm now what? weigh pros/cons i guess, or send youtube an email?

Answer (score 13):

Has everyone forgotten the Windows API libraries? To embed ANY window you simply need a combination of [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541(v=vs.85).aspx). To hide the title bar you can use [SetWindowLong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591(v=vs.85).aspx) and if you need to hide other parts around the window (e.g. address bar) you can easily use [HwndHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.aspx).

C++ Example of embedding Notepad:

```
HWND Window = FindWindow("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad");
if (Window != nullptr)
{
    SetParent(Window, hwnd);
    SetWindowPos(Window, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
    RedrawWindow(Window, nullptr, nullptr, RDW_INVALIDATE);
    ShowWindow(Window, SW_SHOW);
}
```

Don't get me wrong, it is hacky, but it does work.

Anyway, Microsoft has made [such a feature now](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/)

Answer (score 8):

The old answers saying this is not possible are now out of date.

Microsoft recently released their version of the Microsoft Edge based webbrowser control. They are calling it "Webview" It is for WPF and Winforms. Here is their official [announcement](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/) with some getting start info from a Windows blog in April 2018.

There is also [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.ui.interop.webviewcontrol) for it as well.

Answer (score 5):

For full Edge Chromium support, as of this note, it looks like the WebView2 control is the most recent offering from Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaFX which uses embedded WebKit engine. Or if you're stuck in .NET then https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser

Comment: $1200 is not a solution.