# What rendering engine does MS Edge use? Can I embed it in C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge, html-rendering

Like in the title. How I can do it when it's possible
I want create browser, what was be amazing !
If anyone can help me, please!
Thanks for advance :)

Comment: Google gave me [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773359/add-new-microsoft-edge-to-web-broswer-control) as first result..

Comment: @SimpleVar  I don't know how to use it. Do you can explain me this? How to apply Edge instead IE?

Answer (score 7):

The Microsoft Edge browser uses [EdgeHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdgeHTML) for its layout/rendering. The Microsoft Edge team wrote [a blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/08/27/creating-your-own-browser-with-html-and-javascript/) demonstrating how one could leverage this to build their own browser around a [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx).

Comment: I've got this! Tks @Sampson :D  
#offtopic  
I got a error while creating UWP project in VS2015 Express for Windows 10 :( It says It can't load an assembly (?). I try reinstall, but if You can, post a solve :)  Tks for advance

Comment: @rysieł If you're having issues creating an app in VS2015 Express, please post a new question for that specifically. If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it.