# How do detect if Edge is available, and set FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION to use Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I've a procedure that gets IE version from the following registry key
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer` and read the value named `Version`.

For newer versions (IE 10 and above), `Version` is 9.x (for example, IE 10 is 9.10.something), and the new `svcVersion` value gives the true IE version.

Then I set `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to the correct browser value for my application.

The problem is that ms edge set this value to 11 like ie11.

Is there any way to retrieve from registry (or any other programmatically way) if is it installed edge?

What is the value to set for edge in `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`?

Comment: What is wrong with the value of 11?

Comment: The 11 value is equal to ie11. Specifically, I need to set the compatibility value for my application in 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION' for the correct browser. The 11 value is equal to ie11 so I cannot set the correct value for ms edge.

Comment: And you have to do this via the registry? You would reject any solution that doesn't read from the registry? It seems to me that what you really should be asking is, "How do I find out the version of Edge that is installed?" Or perhaps, "How do detect if Edge is available, and then set  `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to use Edge?" That said, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32034725/505088) you cannot get web browser control to use Edge in any case.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question... the aswer you links said also that the possible value to set to `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` exists as `dword:00002ee1`. Is it (or will it be) possible to set the `TWebBrowser` compatibility with edge?

Comment: That answer is wrong. Read the most upvoted answer.