# Is there any option to use other browser on MFC windows application

Tags: mfc, webbrowser-control

Hi I am developing MFC windows application,in that i call webpage using webBrowser control,Actually in web page we use lot of script based on CSS3, My agent run the application on windows xp system, if open in webBrowser control by default  call Microsoft IE browser8.  so it block the script. so i need to use chrome in webBrowser control.

So how to change ?

Note:Need to open inside windows application,not open outside browser.

Comment: There is no such way. The web browser control always uses IE internally. This is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773359/add-new-microsoft-edge-to-web-browser-control) asking for Edge in the webbrowser control

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). You are looking to solve a different issue.