# JavaScript won't run on Internet Explorer within web browser control

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio, internet-explorer, default-browser

I am attempting to develop an application in VB that uses a web browser to go to a specific site. The problem is that the JavaScript applet on the website won't load through the internal browser. It works on both Edge and Chrome, but not through Visual Studio or Internet Explorer. I have scoured the internet options, making sure that it can run scripts. I also enabled the ability for the web browser to be used as a scripting object in my code. I have run Windows updates as well. I guess I'm looking for 1 of 2 solutions. Either a way to fix my browser so I can test and use my application or a way to change the default browser in Visual Studio itself (I already changed the external editor to Chrome, but it had no effect on my application). Can someone help me? Is there a way to embed the user's default browser into my application so that other users don't run into the same problem if I ever distribute my application?

-Verified that scripts and ActiveX were enabled in my internet options

-Attempted to change internal browser

-Ran Windows updates

No change.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Windows Forms and the WebBrowser control. You can use the new Edge WebView2 control, which uses the Chromium-based Edge browser instead of IE. See [Add new Microsoft Edge to web browser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31773359/215552)

Comment: I agree with Heretic Monkey's comment. If the JavaScript can't run in Internet Explorer, of course it can't run in WebBrowser control as WebBrowser control uses IE engine. You can try to use [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/get-started) instead of WebBrowser control.